# Стихограмма с непонятными словами

Tags: словоизменение

В одной из так называемых стихограмм Дмитрия Алексеевича Пригова встречаются такие строки:
*Парк культуры, Скверкультуры, Тропикильтуры, Проливультуры*
А какая ещё строка есть в этой стихограмме?
*а) Полуостровуры; б) Моретуры; в) Заливультуры; г) Полекультуры; д) Перешеекуры.*

Comment: В чём фишка, где интрига?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь ищите.
http://www.vavilon.ru/texts/prigov5-13.html

Смысла в том нет.

Answer (score 0):

а) Полуостровуры

Доказать не могу, ищите и читайте.

Comment: Прочитанного давно и случайно, но потом был разговор на эту тему, спорили - нашли, поэтому запомнила. В Интернете даже не искала, времени жалко. Но вот Вам же ссылку дали, я оказалась права.